# XSLT filter for Yes/No Column/Field in SharePoint Custom List for SharePoint Designer DataView WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, data-view-web-part, filter, xpath

I'm trying this with no luck:

```
  [@ActiveStatus='Yes']
```

also tried 1, '1', 'True' .. get no rows back.. If I remove the filter I get back all rows.

full line in code view looks like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row [@ActiveStatus='Yes']"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your nearly there its just the syntax of the parameter filter.

Try:-

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[ActiveStatus='Yes']"/>
```

There are some good examples in this MSDN article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950787.aspx

Comment: Tried that- did not work. Keep in mind my code was generated by the Dataview XSLT filter editor in SharePoint Designer 2007. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you validated the field is being pulled into your view by dropping it in an xsl:value-of select="@fieldname"

You could also use identity transform as your xsl to validate the variable is coming through and the value.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will find this useful. In my case (MOSS 2007, DVWP), the following solution helped me:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Published=1]" />
```

@Published is Yes/No field.